# How to use a column in a queried table to update a column in the source table in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, power-query

I have a source table that is being broken out into two different tables using Query. The tables are essentially just filtered versions of the source table. I would like for people to be able to use a column at the end of the table to leave comments and would like those comments to stick with their respective rows even as they drop off from this "filtered" table. Is there a way to backwards populate the source table from only that column in the queried table?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! Yes, [**there is such a method**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653178/inserting-text-manually-in-a-custom-column-and-should-be-visible-on-refresh-of-t) - it has been described more than once on a variety of resources

Comment: Could you provide a sample about the source table and how was it broken 2 tables?